# Default variant options on Sylius product show page

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I am using Sylius eCommerce framework. I want to preselect product options for provided route parameters. I created a custom route for the product show page. An additional parameter of the route should result in another pre-selection (default value) of the product option.

For example `http://example.org/products/t-shirt/red` will add the route parameter `color=red` and preselect the color option the the value "red".

Actually I am not sure how to solve my problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem providing the parameter from the main request to the rendered one:

```
{{ render(url('sylius_shop_partial_cart_add_item', {'template': '@SyliusShop/Product/Show/_addToCart.html.twig', 'productId': product.id, 'manufacturer': app.request.get('myparam')})) }}
```

An in the rendered template I used this value for the default param:

```
{{ form_row(option_form, { 'attr': { 'data-option': option_form.vars.name, 'disabled': 'disabled' }, 'value': ~ app.request.get('myparam') }) }}
```

I think it's not the best solution but it fits my needs.